# print elements of Dataset[List[Array[String]]] in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am looking for a way to print the elements of Dataset[List[Array[String]]].Is there any way to do it? I know dataset[Array(string)] can be printed as

```
for(each <- dataset.collect){
    print(each.mkString(","))
}
```

Comment: can't you check with `dataset.collect().foreach(println)`?

Comment: you should do dataset.foreach(list => list.map(array => println(array.mkString(","))))

Comment: @ramesh its not working .nothing is getting printed on spark2-shell

Comment: .show is showing that elements are inside wrapped array

Comment: you will have to update with some sample data and the steps on how you got Dataset[List[Array[String]]] and I guess a udf function will do the trick for you

Comment: @ramesh dataset.collect.foreach(list => list.map(array => println(array.mkString(","))))  worked for me

Comment: yes I saw the answer :) You can accept your answer

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me,

`datasetname.collect().foreach(list => list.map(array => println(array.mkString(","))))`